# Classes to use for a flexible image selection/tagging widget in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm new with Qt and am looking for advice on how to structure this.

I want a flexible widget that can display a set of images (normally read from a directory but other sources too) and let the user select images with the arrow keys and/or mouse and also apply custom tags.

For example there might be 5 tags defined by the application. A user can press a key to select one, and then a little icon would appear in or near the image preview showing that it was selected for that tag.

Would I need to implement this from scratch via drawing on a QWidget or is there something that would make a sensible base class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [QListView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlistview.html#details) base class, and then subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#details).
There is an [example here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/itemviews-stardelegate.html) which might help you.